# Unable to create web sql table in chrome version above 60

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova, web-sql, phonegap

I am getting the following error while trying to create a table in websql.

```
SQLTransaction': Iterator getter is not callable
```

It is working fine in chrome with version below 60. How to fix this issue?

sample code is

```
 var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024);

db.transaction(function (tx) {  
   tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LOGS (id unique, log)');
});
```